# example of common cpu intensive tasks

Tags: algorithm, cpu

For testing of a parallelization tool I'm looking for examples of tasks or algorithms which are:

1. cpu intensive
2. parallelizable
3. have relatively small input and output
4. are commonly used in everyday programming (i.e. not just by scientists and algorithm developers)

I've found many examples but none of them satisfies number 4. The most obvious one being prime factorization. Traveling Salesman Problem is another.

To satisfy number 3 I think algorithms should not have linear or close to linear complexities such as sorting.

Comment: If you're a graphic programmer: shaders.

Comment: I guess video encoding satisfies all your conditions.. Check [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) If you encode HEVC (h265) then you will be working both with minimum size files and the heaviest loads.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of time consuming tasks:

1. Iterate through great amount of data ... which violates point 3 (unless you create your data on the fly)
2. Do time consuming computation on small data ... which violates point 4.

What I could suggest is create big std::vector of basic type and perform simple operation on every element of it (insert random value / modify by random value) or sort it

This will be cpu intensive, it's easy to split into multiple threads, you can generate your data on the fly (small input but still huge memory footprint), and it's non-algorithmic.

Answer (score 0):

Several image processing filters are time consuming and highly parallelizable.

For instance the median or bilateral or non-local-means filter of a large diameter. These are useful in image denoising.

Typical image sizes are a few MB. A nice and useful application is to allow real-time feedback on the adjustable parameters, which requires running times under the second.

Hard problems with an exponential behavior are not the ideal target, as their running time varies in large ranges, and you will be restricted to a small range of N, making the investigations somewhat artificial.

Linear algebra will provide a number of algorithms with an N³ behavior for N² storage. Tey are heavily used in physical simulation code.

Comment: Does it satisfy 4?

Comment: I think the criteria (4) is supposed to be little compromising too.